# JSOM: get_isSiteAdmin () is not distinguishing between users and administrator of site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, administrator, sharepoint-jsom

```
   if (user.get_isSiteAdmin()) 
    {
    document.cookie = "licence=yes";
    }
```

**I am using user.get_isSiteAdmin() but its always giving value false I can not give permission to site site collection**

```
Site Collection - Full Control
```

**in AppMenifest.xml file**

is there any other way to get site administrator ?

Answer (score 0):

@user11869887,

Just have a test this JSOM function on my SPO environment, it works fine here.
[image]

you may need to explicitly initialize the object/properties, or it will always return false as the related property is null.

BR

Comment: I have tried this but its not working in my case here is code which I have written its still giving value false of get_isSiteAdmin

var user = web.get_currentUser();

this.clientContext.load(user);

this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(() => {
         if (user.get_isSiteAdmin()) {
                      document.cookie = "licence=yes";

                    }
}

Comment: How about "_spPageContextInfo.isSiteAdmin"?  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1109529/spPageContextInfo-in-SharePoint

Comment: **These methods works fine when I give permission full-control to site collection in AppMenifest.xml file. Otherwise they are giving value false of isSiteAdmin and I can't give full-control permission to site collection**